# Radio buttons missing from close vote popup

Tags: support, google-chrome

Clicking the close link on a question opens up a close vote popup, that no longer shows the radio buttons on the left that indicate your selection.  You can click on the actual text and it will allow a selection, however, it doesn't display that any longer.

[image]

Edit:

It started working correctly for two close votes, but just happened again, here is another example:

[image]

Comment: Can't repro that. What browser?

Comment: Chrome 11.0.696.68

Comment: @balpha, strange.  It is working now.  I saw the popup missing radio buttons 3 separate times on more than one SE site.  Now, each time I click close, I see the radio buttons.

Comment: The only way I can get this to repro is by casting my vote then re-opening the 'close' UI. Naturally, I can't re-select and re-submit at this point. Oh, and @jzd, Chrome's at v12.0.742.91 - get with the times, man!

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment, yes that would be normal behavior, but this was the first time I clicked close for that question.

Comment: @jzd: Ya, figured that - just sayin'.

Comment: @balpha,  just upgraded my browser to 12.0.742.91, and restarted it.  It is happening again, I added another example.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment, also if you click on the close vote after you already have voted the title should say "You have already voted" instead of "why should this question be closed?"

Comment: I get this occasionally (and have done for previous versions of Chrome), but it seems to go away if I restart the browser. I've yet to discern a pattern.

Comment: I should add that the buttons are still there and clickable - just not visible.

Comment: isn't it funny that a lot of these web page problems are related to Chrome ?

Comment: @ChrisF There's a long-standing Windows-specific rendering bug in Chrome related to this, if I recall correctly, so it might be that.